# Remark 4.3.15 in Liu: constancy of fibers dimensions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In remark 4.3.15, Liu says that for a flat morphism of irreducible varieties, the dimension of fibers is constant.

I know that is right when $f:X\to Y$ is **surjective** flat but I don't see how to remove this hypothesis.

I know that $f(U)$ is dense in $Y$ for all $U\subseteq X$ open but this don't help because in general $f(\overline{U})\neq \overline{f(U)}$.

Maybe a forgetting from the author, but this doesn't appear in the errata.

Comment: He's directly referencing a result, so I would be inclined to include all hypotheses of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right. In the affine case, let $R$ be a domain, and let $f \in R$ be a nonunit. Then the localization map $R \to R_f$ induces an flat morphism of irreducible schemes $\text{Spec}(R_f) \to \text{Spec}(R)$, but since $f$ is not a unit, the morphism is not surjective and some fibers will be empty.

On the other hand the dimensions of the non-empty fibers will be constant though, as observed in Keenan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this might be overkill, but a flat morphism of varieties is open, so you can always replace the target $Y$ by the set-theoretic image $f(X)$ of $f$, which is an open subscheme of $Y$. The induced morphism $X\rightarrow f(X)$ has the same fibers (scheme-theoretically and in particular set-theoretically) and is a flat surjective map of irreducible varieties.

Comment: But elements of $Y\setminus f(X)$ have fibers empty hence don't have same dimension of the (constant) dimension of fiber over $f(X)$??

Comment: Right, so say "non-empty fibers." If you don't, as you observe, it's trivially the case that not every fiber will have the same dimension.